# extend ubuntu partition in VM

Tags: ubuntu, partition, virtual-machine, gparted

I have Ubuntu as virtual machine guest hosted in esxi server. The Ubuntu disk storage was 5 GB and I wanted to extend the disk up to 30 GB. I extended it via esxi client, and now I see this in Ubuntu terminal

```
root@linux:/temp# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             5.6G  5.3G   31M 100% /
none                  497M  184K  497M   1% /dev
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
none                  502M  108K  502M   1% /var/run
none                  502M  4.0K  502M   1% /var/lock
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw

root@linux:/temp# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001c70e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         743     5964800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             743        3917    25490433    5  Extended
/dev/sda3               1           1         992+  8e  Linux LVM
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda5            2025        3917    15192064   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
root@linux:/temp#
```

How can I extend the sda1 to full 32 GB as showed in `fdisk -l` output ?

I tried to boot from gparted and can see following

[image]

I the sda1 cannot be resized, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to a situation where you have a larger disk, without having a extended the partition to use the available space. You will need to use a disk utility of some sort while `/dev/sda1` is unmounted.

I would suggest using an .iso version of [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) on the host which you can mount as a DVD drive on the Ubuntu guest. Boot the VM into the Gparted disk, with Gparted operating in live mode, and extend `/dev/sda1` to fill the available space.

Gparted is a fairly easy to use program, with an intuitive interface but there are detailed instructions on its use [here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual).